# Lines are displaying while rendering tile based kpi(mbtiles) on map

Tags: dictionary, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, mbtiles, kpi

I have mvt layer which has icon layer on it,I'm using deck gl for data visualisation on map, on mbtiles loading I see dashed lines at the junction of each tile on the icon layer, please suggest me a property which is able to fix this issue

I tried to modify properties like linewidth and sizescale which don't make it work,please suggest some other whcih will make it work